# How to assign a string to an object in drake?

Tags: r

I am trying to "parameterize" a drake script by assign a character to an object but I get this warning:

```
plan <- drake_plan(commencement = "dec2017")
make(plan)
Warning messages:
```

> 1: missing input files:   dec2017
>   2: File 'dec2017' was built or processed, but the file itself does not exist

Everything works fine if I `loadd('commencement')` but I am not what's the non-existant file that is being created. That creates issues later on in the script because `commencement` is embedded in files path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue which is going to be fixed in newer versions of drake.

All you need to do to get your code to work is to run:

```
pkgconfig::set_config("drake::strings_in_dots" = "literals")
```

before `drake_plan`. This tells drake to treat strings as strings, instead of filenames. Alternatively you can pass the argument `strings_as_dots = "literals"` directly to `drake_plan`.

File inputs and outputs need to be specified manually in this mode with `file_in` and `file_out`.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand drake, you mostly deal with functions.
One workaround would be this

```
foo <- function() "dec2017"
plan <- drake_plan(commencement = foo())
make(plan)
#> target commencement
```